# Problem after upgrading to "Stretch"

Tags: raspbian, update, raspbian-stretch

When issuing a "sudo apt-get update" after upgrading to "Stretch" I receive the following messages, eleven in all:

> sudo apt-get update
>   Hit:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
>   .....
>   Hit:7 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
>   .....
>   Reading package lists... Done

The hardware is a Pi 3 running as an always-on media server via Ethernet: wireless is disabled. The SD card shows 17GB free (using "df h").

It was necessary to "sudo apt autoremove". That said, Sonarr, SABnzbd & Plex updated correctly.

Everything else (including access to the Internet) appears to be working correctly.

NB: I have similar issues after upgrading a Pi 2B.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: As this is a major version upgrade, we recommend using a clean image; these are available from the Downloads page on our site as usual.

Upgrading an existing Jessie image is possible, but is not guaranteed to work in every circumstance. If you wish to try upgrading a Jessie image to Stretch, we strongly recommend taking a backup first – we can accept no responsibility for loss of data from a failed update.